# How to insert class several time to render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="react-15.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return React.DOM.h1(null, "Hello world!!");
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld, null), document.getElementById("content"));

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

this works well.

Now I want to insert `HelloWorld`  class into `ReactDOM.render` function

In legacy React I could write like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>,
     <HelloWorld/>,
     <HelloWorld/>,
     <HelloWorld/>, 
     document.getElementById("content"));
```

Please help to write analog for my library version

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDOM.render` accepts only two attributes, React element and DOM selector.

Therefore, you need to wrap four `HelloWorld`s into single div.

JSX:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>
  <HelloWorld />
  <HelloWorld />
  <HelloWorld />
  <HelloWorld />
</div>, document.getElementById("content"))
```

React elements:

```
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div", null,
        React.createElement(HelloWorld),
        React.createElement(HelloWorld),
        React.createElement(HelloWorld),
        React.createElement(HelloWorld)
), document.getElementById("content"));
```

[jsbin output](https://jsbin.com/toqirilozo/edit)